# iOS timed functions

Tags: ios, time, background

So I have an app that has to check for a change in the background once very 2000 seconds. Unfortunately, it appears that the app delegate suspends time when in the background. Is there an api that I have overlooked that will allow me to do this?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

 [self performSelector:@selector(newvoidfunction)
               withObject:nil
               afterDelay:2000.0];
}
```

Comment: Please do a bit of searching. There are plenty of existing questions that cover this.

Comment: I have, but all I have found for the last 36 hours are others saying that there is a suspension of time...there has to be an alternative...

Comment: Why does there have to be an alternative? This is a mobile device with limited memory and power, you can't just do anything at any time.